# strange issue with datatable after reset

Tags: vb.net, datatable, reset

I have the simple code:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim table As New DataTable
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    TextBox1.Text = table.Rows.Count
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    table.Columns.Add()
    TextBox1.Text = table.Rows.Count
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    table.Rows.Add()
    TextBox1.Text = table.Rows.Count
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    table.Reset()
    TextBox1.Text = table.Rows.Count
End Sub
End Class
```

When the form is loaded i can add some columns and rows and everything works fine. I can see every added column or row.
After table.reset() i trying to add some rows, but can see only column headers without any rows. At the same time the textbox shows a right amount of added (invisible?) rows.
Is it a bug or i just forgot something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want delete all rows in the table, you can use `table.clear()` instead `table.reset()` because reset.methode will clear all including the columns

About DataTable.Clear -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clear.aspx

About DataTable.Reset -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.reset.aspx

Comment: Yes, I know about datatable.clear and I think that the possible solution is:    
    table.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 0 To table.Columns.Count - 1
    table.Columns.RemoveAt(0)
    Next

Comment: @user2173772: You don't need anything after `table.Clear`, it will clean up your rows.

Comment: But I need to remove a columns too.

Comment: If you want to start with fresh table .. why dont you use `table = New DataTable` and add with `DataGridView1.DataSource = table` ?

Comment: That's what i want. Thank you :D

Comment: @user2173772: oops I really thought your intention is to remove rows only. If it's also the columns, a `Reset` should be better, because -> `If a DataSet includes a DataTable, the table will still be part of the DataSet after the table is reset.` And yeah, don't forget to accept/upvote matzone's answer.

Comment: Done. Thank you, guys, for the discussion.